# How to find which maven dependency is downloading a jar?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, maven, java-15

I am facing an issue in a spring boot mongodb application, where I am getting the following exception

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.mongodb.connection.ConnectionPoolSettings$Builder
com.mongodb.connection.ConnectionPoolSettings$Builder.maxWaitQueueSize(int)
```

From what I found, I have to update the mongodb-driver version to a version higher than 3.5. The current version in use is 3.2.2

In the application's pom.xml, there is no mongodb-driver dependency at all. From my understanding, some other dependency is downloading this mongodb-driver jar. How to find out which dependency is downloading it and how to make that particular dependency download a higher version of mongodb-driver jar?

Comment: You can use the [dependency plugin `tree`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html) command to find out the source.

Comment: What is your spring boot version ?

Comment: @R.G I am using springboot version 1.4.2

Comment: If you can upgrade the spring boot version , the latest supported `mongodb-driver-core` version is `4.2.3` . [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/dependency-versions.html)

Answer (score 5):

You have two options:

### Eclipse IDE

- open your maven project
- open the pom.xml
- click on dependency hierarchy
- put the name (or part) of the jar in the search box
- you will see the tree of dependencies related to your jar

[image: mvn]

### Using maven plugin

As @Naman said, you can use the [dependency:tree](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html) plugin.

You just need maven on your shell. To see the complete tree, execute this:

`mvn dependency:tree` or search with wildcards

`mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=*common*`

[image: mvn-tree]